# Branch deep-linking SDK and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, branch.io

I'm trying to make use of Branch's deep-linking (particularly deferred deep-linking) capabilities in my Ionic project.  The problem is, their docs for Cordova/Ionic are incomplete.  After installing their Cordova plugin, my application still does not recognize the Branch provider as described in the documentation.  However, I can't for the life of me find any information about a provider name to declare for the Cordova plugin or requiring it in my angular module.

I've tried declaring `Branch`, `branch`, `io.branch.sdk`, and a bunch of other names, not recognized.

Calling any of the Branch functions described in the [Branch SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking) docs will result in a reference error.  I've reached out to their technical support, but their response was essentially that their in-house team is inexperienced in Cordova/Ionic so they'll have to get back to me after consulting with their Ionic contractor, which I really don't have time for.  Has anyone gotten this working in Ionic/Cordova?

Comment: Where's your branch.js file located?

Comment: From my app root directory /plugins/io.branch.sdk/www/ where running `cordova plugin add https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK.git --variable BRANCH_KEY=your-branch-key --variable URI_SCHEME=your-app-uri-scheme-without-colon-and-slashes` installs it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are installing npm Branch via **branch-cordova-sdk** instead of https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK.git

remove the old if already installed

```
cordova plugin remove io.branch.sdk
```

install the correct npm (fill in xxxx)

```
cordova plugin add branch-cordova-sdk --variable BRANCH_KEY=xxxx --variable URI_SCHEME=xxxx
```

Second, make sure your Branch init is in the correct location:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   ... 

    $ionicPlatform.on('deviceready', function(){
      Branch.initSession().then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        alert('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
    });
  });
})
```

Finally, you can test if it is working by:

1) Running the app after installing the Branch plugin

2) Safari -> Develop -> APP_NAME -> index.html -> Console -> "Branch"
[image]
Overall,

1) Make sure you are always testing Branch on a device (not a simulator or browser)

2) Make sure you are npm installing branch-cordova-sdk instead of the github link

3) You can find the SDK documentation here: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, thank you.  You should update the SDK docs on your dashboard to reflect this.  It would have taken me forever to figure out.  I do appreciate the speedy responses from your team though!

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch here: my apologies for the delay. We're currently working on a major update to the Cordova/Ionic documentation, because we've had similar feedback on several occasions recently.

In the meantime, feel free to post an issue on our [SDK GitHub repo](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking). Our contractors monitor this, so you will likely get a more timely response there.

Comment: Thank you.  As I said in my comment to Ethan, I do appreciate the speedy responses from your tech team!